# UnhandledException event handler not catching ThreadException

Tags: .net, vb.net, error-handling

I have the following code in the ApplicationEvents.vb file to catch UnhandledExceptions

```
Namespace My

    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
            MessageBox.Show("error")
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

However, this does not catch exceptions that occur on other threads, ThreadExceptions.  I do have some error handling in the other threads and other methods to prevent and work around errors, but I would like to provide information for debugging purposes when an application fails unexpectedly.  Since the error handling I have in the ApplicationEvents file doesn't take care of these, what can I do to provide some information for ThreadExceptions in general?

Edit:

I've tried Hans' solution below, but no dice unfortunately.  I have the code as he's written it more or less exactly, just the message box is different.  When I get it working I may add an error log or have it send a message to our support inbox.  Anyway, here is what I have.  Attached to a button I have a small sub that starts a new thread and throws an exception for the purposes of testing:

```
Private Sub Label2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, VyVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
    Dim newThread As New Thread(AddressOf ErrorThread)
    newThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub ErrorThread()
    Throw New System.NullReferenceException
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the method described below isn't quite working yet.  I had high hopes that this would be caught, but the application still fails silently.

Edit:

Whelp, Hans deleted his answer... I'm not sure why, but in interest of being thorough I'll post the code that I'm working with right now and a brief description of what happens when I step through:

In the ApplicationEvents.vb file:

```
Partial Friend Class MyApplication
    Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        If Not System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached Then
            AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf AllUnhandledExceptions
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub AllUnhandledExceptions(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
        Dim ex = DirectCast(e.ExceptionObject, Exception)
        MessageBox.Show("Message" & ex.innerException.ToString, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Environment.Exit(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHRForException(ex))
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
        AllUnhandledExceptions(sender, New UnhandledExceptionEventArgs(e.Exception, True))
    End Sub

End Class
```

That's what I'm working with at the moment, and all credit to Hans Passant for getting me that far.  Here's what happens as I step through.  The startup handler runs, some other code runs, and the form displays.  Clicking the button on the form allows me to step through the code that generates the new thread (normally I use tasks but in this case I just fired of a thread, same difference, different implementation as far as I know, more flexibility with tasks) which begins and throws the null ref exception.  Execution proceeds to the `AllUnhandledExceptions` sub and to the `MessageBox.Show` line.  Hitting F8 from that line returns me to the original throw line.  (I've commented out the If statement in the startup routine to be able to step though like this.)  If I build the application it still fails silently.  Windows tells me that the application must end, but does not display my message box.  Errors in the UI thread still trigger the message box.

Any further ideas, tips or tricks are appreciated.  Thanks again for your time and suggestions everyone.

Edit:  WORKING!  Hans' answer did work after a slight tweak.  Details to be posted in a moment...

So if anyone can explain in greater depth why this works after this slight change.  I'm all ears.  After poking around in debug, here's what I found, and I'm slightly embarrassed I didn't catch it sooner:

Execution does go to the `AllUnhandledExceptions` sub after the exception is thrown on the new thread, just as anticipated.  However, when I was poking around my code in debug I finally noticed something - the line `Dim ex = DirectCast(e.ExceptionObject, Exception)` was resulting in the object reference ex not being set to an instance of an object.  I realized that the null reference exception I was getting wasn't my original null reference exception, it was a null reference exception on ex when I tried to use ex.innerexception.ToString in my message box.  I switched and rather than using ex I'm using the e object passed to the sub like so:  `MessageBox.Show(Message & e.ExceptionObject.ToString, "Fatal Error", MessageButtons, MessageIcon)` and lo and behold, it works!  Moreover, it works for exceptions thrown both on the UI thread and new threads.

So... there's my resolution.  I'm still not sure why Hans' answer is missing, but if he'd be kind enough to repost it I'd like to give him credit formally, not that he needs the points I'm sure.

Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I would ensure that your thread(s) are properly handling exceptions. Your main thread will not pick up on unhandled exceptions in spawned threads.

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but we have legacy com objects that have a tendency to throw unexpected exceptions for... well if I could always tell you why I wouldn't be worrying about this.  It's a fairly minor inconvenience to the users, they just restart the application and 99 times out of 100 it works the next time through.  I'd like to put something in place to provide more feedback so I can update the code to handle these unexpected issues more gracefully in the future.